# Failed to load AppContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to run test in a project with spring and hibernate but I get the "Failed to load AppContext" error when testing the file.

My project structure is:

Spring

Source Packages

```
         pe.edu.upc.configuration
                SpringContext.xml
         pe.edu.upc.domain
                Categoria.java
                Producto.java
         pe.edu.upc.repository
                CategoriaRepository.java
                CategoriaRepository.java
```

TestPackages
             pe.edu.upc.spring
                  configuracion

```
         pe.edu.upc.test
               ProductoTest
```

The "configuracion" file contains this:  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/java//pe/edu/upc/configuration/SpringContext.xml" })

Answer (score 0):

Can you type the contents of your SpringContext.xml file? so we can see what is the context you are loading on your test.